# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.3 Gb

Tags: r

I have a very large data. I am trying to apply Multinomial Logistic Regression to this data. 
While using "multinom" function I am getting error:

> ```
>                      **Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.3 GB**
> ```

I am not able to resolve this error since yesterday. 
I am using "ffdf" to read the data in R-studio.

Have tried `memory.limit()` and `memory.size()` but they didn't resolve my issue.

**My RAM is 8 GB and I am using a 64-bit Windows laptop.**

**> sessionInfo()**

> `R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)`
>
> `locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252
>   [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252`
>
> `attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base`
>
> `other attached packages:
>   [1] nnet_7.3-12   ffbase_0.12.3 ff_2.2-13     bit_1.1-12`
>
> `loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] tools_3.3.1     fastmatch_1.0-4`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks & regards, 
Pragati Jain

Comment: Can anyone please provide me with the links of the solution to this problem as it is marked as Duplicate question.

Comment: Have tried the solutions given in other links with same question but haven't got it resolved. Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: I had same problem with R mlogit function. Used 200K rows aith 10 predictor variables and a 4-category dependent variable

I got the same error message.
I restarted my R Studio and then tried again and the function ran fine. 
I am assuming it has to do with memory. Especially if you have stored a bunch of stuff in your environment (variables, models, data frames etc.)